# join values in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I would like to run following postgreSQL query in SQLalchemy:

```
select c.*
from comments c
join (
  values
    (1,1),
    (3,2),
    (2,3),
    (4,4)
) as x (id, ordering) on c.id = x.id
order by x.ordering
```

Is it possible to join something like list of lists or list of tuples and use them to provide ordering in SQLalchemy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from sqlalchemy import *

from yourdbmodule import dbsession


VALUES = ((1, 1), (3, 2), (2, 3), (4, 4))


temp_table = Table(
    'temp_table', MetaData(),
    Column('id', INT, primary_key=True),
    Column('ordering', INT),
    prefixes=['TEMPORARY']
)
temp_table.create(bind=dbsession.bind, checkfirst=True)


dbsession.execute(temp_table.insert().values(VALUES))


# Now you can query it
dbsession.query(Comments)\
    .join(temp_table, Comments.id == temp_table.c.id)\
    .order_by(temp_table.c.ordering)\
    .all()
```

Comment: It uses two queries and a temp table when a single query will do.

Comment: @univerio thanks. I saw you did it in different way (one query) below, but drootnar asks about sqlalchemy, without any raw elements of query, I know solution you wrote. Anyway does your solution work with other databases (not only postgreSQL)?

Comment: He's asking how to get SQLAlchemy to produce that particular query for PostgreSQL; whether that query works on different backends is a different issue. Regardless, OTOH, SQL Server and Oracle also support this syntax.

Comment: @univerio sorry my fault, didn't notce that. About support, yeah I know that only MySQL doesn't support your solution. Gosh, I wish to answer under other solutions, need to earn more reputation points. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3):

See the [PGValues recipe](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/PGValues) for how to make SQLAlchemy compile the `VALUES` clause:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql import column
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import FromClause


class values(FromClause):
    named_with_column = True

    def __init__(self, columns, *args, **kw):
        self._column_args = columns
        self.list = args
        self.alias_name = self.name = kw.pop('alias_name', None)

    def _populate_column_collection(self):
        for c in self._column_args:
            c._make_proxy(self)


@compiles(values)
def compile_values(element, compiler, asfrom=False, **kw):
    columns = element.columns
    v = "VALUES %s" % ", ".join(
        "(%s)" % ", ".join(
                compiler.render_literal_value(elem, column.type)
                for elem, column in zip(tup, columns))
        for tup in element.list
    )
    if asfrom:
        if element.alias_name:
            v = "(%s) AS %s (%s)" % (v, element.alias_name, (", ".join(c.name for c in element.columns)))
        else:
            v = "(%s)" % v
    return v


>>> x = values([column("id", Integer), column("ordering", Integer)], (1, 1), (3, 2), (2, 3), (4, 4), alias_name="x")
>>> q = session.query(Comment).join(x, Comment.id == x.c.id).order_by(x.c.ordering)
>>> print(q)
SELECT comments.id AS comments_id 
FROM comments JOIN (VALUES (1, 1), (3, 2), (2, 3), (4, 4)) AS x (id, ordering) ON comments.id = x.id ORDER BY x.ordering
```

Comment: The link provided by [@univerio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341730/univerio) doesn't work anymore. The good URL is https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/PGValues
. In Sqlalchemy14, the Values construct already exist. FMI, https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.values

Answer (score 1):

The solution of univerio works great, except it throws an error if you select a column from the given values:

```
>>> q = session.query(Comment, c.x.id).join(x, Comment.id == x.c.id).order_by(x.c.ordering)
>>> q.all()
ProgrammingError (ProgrammingError) table name "x" specified more than once
```

This is because the VALUES get populated into the FROM and the JOIN block

```
>>> print(q)
SELECT comments.id AS comments_id, x.ordering as x_ordering
FROM (VALUES (1, 1), (3, 2), (2, 3), (4, 4)) AS x (id, ordering), comments
JOIN (VALUES (1, 1), (3, 2), (2, 3), (4, 4)) AS x (id, ordering) ON comments.id = x.id ORDER BY x.ordering
```

The solution is to hide the VALUES from the FROM statement:

```
class values(FromClause):
named_with_column = True

def __init__(self, columns, *args, **kw):
    self._column_args = columns
    self.list = args
    self._hide_froms.append(self)  # This line fixes the above error
    self.alias_name = self.name = kw.pop('alias_name', None)

def _populate_column_collection(self):
    for c in self._column_args:
        c._make_proxy(self)
```

Now it works fine:

```
>>> q = session.query(Comment, c.x.id).join(x, Comment.id == x.c.id).order_by(x.c.ordering)
>>> print(q)
SELECT comments.id AS comments_id, x.ordering as x_ordering
FROM comments JOIN (VALUES (1, 1), (3, 2), (2, 3), (4, 4)) AS x (id, ordering) ON comments.id = x.id ORDER BY x.ordering
```

Comment: We used this in production and it has a serious flaw (memory leak):
`self._hide_froms.append(self)` writes to class attribute, thus it's constantly growing.  The more times you use pg_values, the more Mem/CPU is used.
Fix: `self._hide_froms = [self]`